# Importing SCSS from a Node Module causes Webpack Errors

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, sass

I have an Angular 7 app, built using [a starter kit called ASPNet Core Angular Universal](https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-angular-universal), and I would like to use SCSS files from a few node modules (Bootstrap, Font Awesome, and MDBootstrap.) I tried importing them in a single scss file, used in an app.component, like this:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
@import '~angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss';
```

But I get errors during build:

> ERROR in ./ClientApp/app/app.component.scss
>   (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./ClientApp/app/app.component.scss) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/svg/arrow_right.svg' in
>   '...'

I tried adding resolve-url-loader in webpack.addition.js, but it didn't work:

```
const sharedModuleRules = [
// sass
{
test: /.scss$/,
loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader']
},
// font-awesome
{ test: /.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000' }
];
```

Comment: I don't think this is the recommended way to build font awesome with Angular. They released an Angular library and module so that the icons are placed in the bundle, and can be tree shaken. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular

Comment: As for the error, I think (if I recommend correctly) you have to configure font awesome variables so it knows where to load resources before you import it. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass#compile

Comment: Thanks. I'll take out the font-awesome import. I'll check if there is a similar solution for Bootstrap and MDBootstrap.